# Backbone requireJs has not been loaded yet for context: _

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Why i get error

> require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Module name "views/concerts/ConcertView"
>   has not been loaded yet for context: _

```
define(function (require) {
var $ = require('jquery'),
    Marionette = require('marionette'),
    WrapperView = require('views/WrapperView'),
    ConcertInfoAddView = require('views/concertInfo/ConcertInfoAddView'),
    ConcertInfoModalView = require('views/concertInfo/ConcertInfoModalView'),
    ConcertInfoWrapperView = require('views/concertInfo/table/ConcertInfoWrapperView'),
    ConcertInfoCollection = require('collections/ConcertInfoCollection'),
    Template = require('text!templates/concerts/concert-main.html');

    var moment = require('moment');

var ConcertView = Marionette.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync');
    },

    modelEvents : {
        sync : function() {
            WrapperView.showChildView('Content', this);
            this.ConcertInfoModalView = new ConcertInfoModalView();
            this.showChildView('createBody', new ConcertInfoAddView({concertId : this.model.get('id')}));
            this.showChildView('tableConcerts', new ConcertInfoWrapperView());
            this.showChildView('modalArea', this.ConcertInfoModalView);
            ConcertInfoCollection.getConcertInfo(this.model.get('id'));
        }
    },

    regions : {
        'createBody' : '.create-body',
        'tableConcerts' : '.table-concerts',
        'modalArea' : '.modal-area'
    },

    template : function (ops) {
        var date = ops.date;
        var dateString = moment.unix(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        ops.date = dateString;
        return _.template(Template)(ops);
    },


    getInfoModalView : function () {
        return this.ConcertInfoModalView;
    },

    onRender : function () {

    }

});

return ConcertView;});
```

Its ConcertView

```
define(function(require) {
var _ = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    Marionette = require('marionette'),
    ConcertInfoModalView = require('views/concertInfo/ConcertInfoModalView'),
    ConcertInfoCollection = require('collections/ConcertInfoCollection'),
    ConcertView = require('views/concerts/ConcertView'),
    Template = require('text!templates/concertInfo/table/concertInfo-item.html');

    var bootbox = require('bootbox');

var ConcertInfoItemView = Marionette.View.extend({

    tagName : 'tr',

    ui : {
        edit : '#editButton',
        delete : '#deleteButton'
    },

    events : {
        'click @ui.edit' : 'edit',
        'click @ui.delete' : 'delete'
    },

    edit : function () {
        var concertModalView = ConcertView.getInfoModalView();
        concertModalView.setModel(this.model);
        $('#concertInfo-edit').modal('show');
    },

    delete : function () {
        var self = this;
        bootbox.confirm({
            size: 'small',
            message: "Are you sure?",
            callback: function(result){
                if(result){
                    self.model.destroy(null, {
                        success : function(model, response) {
                            noty({
                                text : response.notice,
                                type : response.type
                            });
                        },
                        error : function (model, response) {
                            if(_.isArray(response.responseJSON.notice)){
                                _.each(response.responseJSON.notice, function (res) {
                                    noty({
                                        text : res,
                                        type : response.responseJSON.type
                                    });
                                });
                            }else{
                                noty({
                                    text : response.responseJSON.notice,
                                    type : response.responseJSON.type
                                });
                            }

                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        });

    },

    template : function(ops) {
        return _.template(Template)(ops);
    }

});

return ConcertInfoItemView;});
```

Its where i require it, why error?

I try not require it here, and require in other file, work fine

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem or not, but I would advise you to use the [amd](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd) format

Comment: Your way of defining AMD is wrong please see above comment by @EmileBergeron

Comment: You can actually use require this way, is the path correct?

Comment: A bit late, but requirejs has a good section in the docs for common errors. Your error specifically: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded